# ShellExView vs ShellMenuView

Tags: terminology

I'm unskilled with computers. Can someone please explain, like I'm 5 years old, the:

1. differences between ShellExView and ShellMenuView?
2. meanings of 'shell extensions' and 'static menu items'? [This comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1435498/how-do-i-remove-organizen-from-the-context-menu-with-shellmenuview#comment2178975_1435498) counsels:

> ShellExView lists shell extensions. ShellMenuView lists only static menu items.

Comment: As an FYI, the Super User question linked seems to have been deleted (prior to any editing).

Comment: @Anaksunaman It was a dead question and auto deleted as "Abandoned, unanswered" by the [Roomba](https://superuser.com/help/roomba)

Answer (score 6):

#### What is the difference between ShellExView and ShellMenuView?

> The ShellExView utility displays the details of shell extensions installed on your computer, and allows you to easily disable and enable each shell extension.

Note:

- Not all Shell Extensions add menu items - only those that are Context Menu Handlers. See below for examples of other types of Shell Extension.

Source [ShellExView - Shell Extension Manager For Windows](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html)

> ShellMenuView is a small utility that displays the list of static menu items that appeared in the context menu when you right-click a file/folder on Windows Explorer, and allows you to easily disable unwanted menu items.

Source [ShellMenuView - Disable/enable context menu items of Explorer](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shell_menu_view.html)

---

#### What is a Shell Extension?

> A shell extension is a COM object that adds some kind of functionality to the Windows shell (Explorer).
>
> There are two parts in the term "shell extension." Shell refers to Explorer, and extension refers to code you write that gets run by Explorer when a predetermined event happens (e.g., a right-click on a .DOC file). So a shell extension is a COM object that adds features to Explorer.
>
> A shell extension is an in-process server that implements some interfaces that handle the communication with Explorer.
>
> There are many types of shell extensions, each type being invoked when different events happen. Here are a few of the more common types, and the situations in which they are invoked:
>
> [image]

Source [The Complete Idiot's Guide to Writing Shell Extensions - Part I - CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/441/The-Complete-Idiot-s-Guide-to-Writing-Shell-Extens)

---

#### What is a Static Menu Item?

In this context, any menu item that appears in the context menu when you right-click a file/folder on Windows Explorer that has **not been added via a Shell Extension**.